# Django migration: Revert or bypass "ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations"

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

while attempting to separate the models in different apps, I bumped to an issue I would need support on:

I have 2 models:

```
class SeriesCompletion(models.Model):
   series = models.ForeignKey(
       'Series', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, )
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                         null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,)
```

and

```
class Series(models.Model):
   ...
   users_who_completed = models.ManyToManyField(
     settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='app1.SeriesCompletion',)
```

which were both located in `app1`

the idea (that worked well in dev environment) was to do a dumpadata, move `SeriesCompletion` to `app2` and do the migrations, than a loaddata to repopulate properly

however, when moving to prod environment, I ran the `app1` migration with the `Series` model with a reference to `app2`:

```
class Series(models.Model):
       ...
       users_who_completed = models.ManyToManyField(
         settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='app2.SeriesCompletion',)
```

It passed in prod, and when moving to do the makemigration for app2, it blocked because of a circular reference: `ValueError: <function ManyToManyField.contribute_to_class.<locals>.resolve_through_model at 0x7f3e531f4400> contains a lazy reference to app2.seriescompletion, but app 'app2' isn't installed.`

I've tried a lot of things since, but I'm always blocked, and I am not able to move forwards doing a migration for `app1` or for `app2` ... or to move backwards returning to the previous migration with `app1`
I always end-up during the pre-migration/pre-makemigrations checks with the error message:

```
ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations
```

Any bright idea to help me get out of this mess?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it took us quite a lot of time, but we were finally able to get out of this mess.

As a matter of facts, we had somewhere in some old migration a `migrations.RunPython(populate_SeriesCompletion)` operation which of course was refering to the `SeriesCompletion` model ... and which was at the origin of the mess

I happen to run into retrocompatibility issues from time to time due to similar `migrations.RunPython` operations when models evolve.

Since some time I'm trying to avoid having `migrations.RunPython` operations in my migrations. I initially thought useing them was a good practice to avoid having things "lost in translation" ... but it seems on the contrary to prove a bad practice.